# How to prevent a console window from being "paused"?

Tags: windows, command-line

I run local network web servers via the cmd prompt and noticed that the `Pause/Break` button will put the server in a state that is quite hard to deal with.

Normally, if the server is not running, the `curl` command would timeout. However, if it is running, but I paused the server accidentally with the `Pause/Break` button, it literally hangs the `curl` command and blocks it indefinitely. I can't do anything to make it time out to generate an `errorlevel` return. When I use `curl -v`, it shows that it is connecting to the server, but then waits indefinitely.

How can I configure my system so that the `Pause/Break` button doesn't do that? Or is there a way to prominently show the paused status?

Comment: Perhaps remap the Pause key to something else, e.g. https://www.howtogeek.com/710290/how-to-remap-any-key-or-shortcut-on-windows-10/ or https://beebom.com/how-remap-keyboard-windows-10/, and map an more obscure key combo to actually perform Pause.

Comment: Normally pressing space resumes from the pause. Does this still break curl, or does it then continue as normal?

Comment: It continues. The issue is I can't tell if the server console is paused, and the people using the server isn't me.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik remapping the button is viable. I'm running AutoHotKey so that's trivially done. I never use the button anyways.

Comment: Note that the windows registry can't remap the pause/break key's scan code (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/38850436/7411885). So something like AutoHotKey is required. Simpler remapping tools like SharpKeys just use the registry and will fail, so keep it in mind